# Unable to visit virtual host over port 443

Tags: linux, apache-2.4, virtualhost, google-compute-engine

I have a Google Compute instance (Debian 8 and Apache) running using Google Compute protocol forwarding to be able to use multiple external IP addresses with one virtual machine instance:

> **Google Compute Protocol Forwarding [(full article)](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/protocol-forwarding/)**
>
> Google Compute Engine supports Protocol Forwarding, which lets you
>   create forwarding rule objects that can send packets to a non-NAT’ed
>   target instance. Each target instance contains a single virtual
>   machine instance that receives and handles traffic from the
>   corresponding forwarding rules.

**The Problem**

I am not able to visit one of the virtual host domains/IP's over port 443. I need this, because I want to enable HTTPS on all these domains.

I have tried multiple options to achieve opening port 443, but none of them works:

**Option 1) Virtual name-based hosts:**

*/etc/apache2/ports.conf*

```
Listen 80

<IfModule ssl_module>
    NameVirtualHost *:443
    Listen 443
</IfModule>

<IfModule mod_gnutls.c>
    NameVirtualHost *:443
    Listen 443
</IfModule>
```

*/etc/apache2/sites-enabled/example.com.conf*

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName example.com
    ServerAlias www.example.com
    DocumentRoot /var/www/website1
</VirtualHost>

<VirtualHost *:443>
    ServerName example.com
    ServerAlias www.example.com
    DocumentRoot /var/www/website1
</VirtualHost>
```

**Option 2) Virtual IP-based hosts:**

*/etc/apache2/ports.conf*

```
Listen 80

<IfModule ssl_module>
    NameVirtualHost *:443
    Listen 443
</IfModule>

<IfModule mod_gnutls.c>
    NameVirtualHost *:443
    Listen 443
</IfModule>

<VirtualHost 192.0.2.5>
 DocumentRoot /var/www/website1
 <Directory /var/www/website1>
  Require all granted
 </Directory>
</VirtualHost>

...
```

Both options work for port 80, but not for port 443.

Answer (score 1):

In ports.conf you need

```
Listen 443
```

and in /etc/apache2/sites-enabled/example.com.conf  you need:

```
SSLEngine On
SSLCertificateFile      /path/to/file.pem
SSLCertificateKeyFile /path/to/file.key
```

where file.pem and file.key are certificate and key

Comment: I have tried `Listen 443` already and the problem is that I generate the certificates with Certbot (https://certbot.eff.org/), but when I try to install them, Certbot gives me an error message: "Failed to connect to 192.0.2.5:433". So it is not able to use port 433 to install the certificates. This is a almost paradox right?

Comment: Did you do **SSLengin on** on virtual host. Also run **netstat -tnlp | grep 443** until you see something here you won't be able to connect.

Comment: Okay, with the `SSLengin on` without the `SSLCertificateFile` and `SSLCertificateKeyFile `. I get at least no results by using `netstat -tnlp | grep 443`, so that's one step further! Thanks

Comment: No you have to have output of **netstat -tnlp | grep 443** as something like **tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:443             0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      2341/apache2** also please use sslcertificate and keyfile.

Comment: Ok, without `SSLEngine on` the output of `netstat -tnlp | grep 443` is `tcp 0 0 0.0.0.0:443 0.0.0.0:* LISTEN 18697/apache2`

Comment: I have succeeded to generate the certificates and added them to my virtual host with SSLEngine on. But I still cannot visit the website over port 443 (or with https://

Comment: See iptables and selinux if they are turned off.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/47577/discussion-between-robbert-and-anirudh-malhotra).

Comment: Do you have a firewall rule configured in your (GCE network to allow)[https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/networking#firewall_rules] port 443?

Comment: Were you able to solve this issue? If so please post the root cause, it will benefit the community. Having a look to the discussion and to [this document](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/protocol-forwarding/),  I would check (besides the already mentioned firewall) that the forwarding rules for port 443 were also appropriately created. The steps to create them specifically for port 80 are described in the section ¨Create your forwarding rule objects.¨ but you should make sure to [include port 443](https://cloud.google.com/sdk/gcloud/reference/compute/forwarding-rules/create).